# Limit REST API access to specific store view

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I am looking for a way to limit the access for specific REST users/roles to specific stores.

I am aware that I can pass a `/store/storeid` parameter for a GET products call, but I can´t use that with orders or customers for example. And to be honest, that call is everything i have found while looking for this topic.

Furthermore this won´t help me when someone is pulling data from a wrong store (multi store system) or from a test store within the Magento instance.

Has anybody got some ideas, code or whatever where to look and what to look for? I have searched for plugins but found none and I don´t want to change the core to lock it down to one store (if that´s possible at least).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly the best option would be to hardcode some checks within the `api.php` file:

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/api.php#L64

Something like this, check that the incoming global `$_SERVER` variable is the store.

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/.htaccess#L133

This would go after the defining of `$apiAlias` as it is where the `?type=rest` is determined to only allow REST specific requests and not SOAP.

```
if($apiAlias == "rest" && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'examplestore.com') {
// or possibly use $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] and/or $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] if you are setting your store 
// variables via .htaccess or configuration
// if($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] == "examplestore-code")   
} else {
    Mage::throwException('REST Access is only possible via pre-defined store');
    // or just die('REST Access is only possible via pre-defined store');
    exit;
}
```

Note: `Mage::throwExcpetion` *MAY* not work in this instance, but can easily just exit silently.

Further research:

- http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/142036931270/magento-2-understanding-the-web-api-architecture

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a look into this. I read about creating custom API endpoints and wondered, if I could solve my problem with a simple additional `/realstore/` endpoint which inherits all functions but sets a fixed Store ID filter. Do you think that´s possible, too?

Comment: @flomei I believe so, you would simply setup your web servers configuration to redirect `realstore/` to the custom `api.php` end point PHP file.